# JSDoc 3 How can I use my own custom templates?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, documentation-generation, jsdoc3

I have a number of custom HTML templates along with a custom publish.js file to help put them together located here in my directory */home/cordonem/bitbucket/workdir/lib/defaults/platform/docs/templates/html* and two custom CSS files and an HTML header file located here in my directory */home/cordonem/bitbucket/workdir/lib/defaults/platform/docs/templates/html/static*.

I would like to run JSDoc 3 and have it use my set of custom templates instead of the default templates. I tried creating the *conf.json* file you see below to link to the correct location for my templates, but it did not work. How can I make it so JSDoc will generate the documentation using my custom templates and CSS?

```
{
"tags": {
    "allowUnknownTags": true
},
"source": {
    "includePattern": ".+\\.js(doc|x)?$",
    "includePattern": ".+\\.c(doc|x)?$",
    "includePattern": ".+\\.h(doc|x)?$",
    "excludePattern": "(^|\\/|\\\\)_"
},
"plugins": [],
"templates": {
    "cleverLinks": false,
    "monospaceLinks": false,
    "default": {
        "outputSourceFiles": true,
        "layoutFile": "./home/cordonem/bitbucket/workdir/lib/defaults/platform/docs/templates/html"
    }
}
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can study these links to use your own custom templates:

- [Configuring JSDoc's Default Template](http://jsdoc.app/about-configuring-default-template.html)
- [jsdoc](http://jsdoc.app/)

I used [docdash](https://github.com/clenemt/docdash) over the default `jsdoc` template. You may follow the instructions as mentioned in [docdash's Github](http://jsdoc.app/) repository. To do this you will need an additional `jsdoc.json` file in your `jsdoc` directory .e.g:

```shell
MyProject/node_modules/jsdoc$ tree -L 1
.
├── jsdoc.json
├── OTHER FILES
├── README.md
└── templates
```